# How to compute this marginal density?

Tags: probability

We know the joint probability density of X and Y :

\begin{equation*}
f(x,y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
2x+2y-4xy & \text{if } 0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le 1,\\
0 & \text{if } else.
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation*}

I am trying to get the marginal density of X. While I was compute de integral, the result is:

$$ f_x(x) = \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} f(x,y)dy = \int_0^{1}(2x+2y-4xy)dy = [2xy+y^2-2xy^2]_0^1 = 1$$

I guess this is a wrong answer, but I do not know which step is wrong. Please help me to find the correct marginal density function of X. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you think is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation is correct.  Both the marginal of $X$ and the marginal of $Y$ are uniform on $[0,1]$.  But since the joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is clearly not equal to the product of the marginals $f_X(x) f_Y(y) = 1 \cdot 1 = 1$, this example shows that $X$ and $Y$ can be identically distributed uniform(0,1) variables that are not independent.

Comment: I see. So, the conditional probability $f_y(y|x=1/4)$ is then equal to $f(x=1/4,y)/f_x(x=1/4) = (1/2+2y-y)/1 = y+1/2$. Is this correct?

Comment: The conditional *density* is $f_Y(y \mid x = 1/4) = y + 1/2$, yes.